# how to debug MATLAB .mex32/.mex64 files with Visual Studio 2010

Tags: matlab, visual-c++

I have a question related to debugging .mex32/.mex64 files. Suppose now I have a file named test.cpp:

```
#include "mex.h" 
#include <iostream>
void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[],
    int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
    mexPrintf("Hello Matlab, and this is a test program\n"); 
}
```

I can then compile and build `test.mex64` with Visual Studio 2010.Then in matlab, I can write the following script to test the function:

```
clc; 
test;
```

Now suppose I want to debug the test.mex64 function, what should I do? The have adopted the following procedure, but failed:

1. Toggle break point at the begging of the line `mexPrintf`with VS2010.
2. With VS2010 from Debug->Attach to Process... select MATLAB.exe.
3. Run MATLAB script `clc; test;`

The error message I have obtained is as follows:

```
The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document.
```

Comment: You might want to look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11220250/how-do-i-profile-a-mex-function-in-matlab/12405131#12405131). It deals with profiling mex on Linux, but similar ideas should be used on Windows. Admittedly, profiling is a bit different, but you may start there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution: when I created the .mexw64 function (test.mexw64 in our case), I copied it to the MATLAB work directory. In order to debug this function, it is important to copy test.pdb file to the MATLAB work directory as well. After doing that, I can debug.

Answer (score 1):

Did you build your mex file with debug option "-g"?